# updating bokeh plot with a bokeh widget in jupyter notebook

Tags: widget, jupyter, bokeh

I want to use bokeh widgets from within a jupyter notebook to update a bokeh plot. My (somewhat hacky) code looks like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, push_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider

output_notebook()

power = 0.5
x = [1,2,3]
y = [i**power for i in x]

fig = figure()
plt = fig.circle(x, y)

def update_plot(power):
    x = plt.data_source.data['x']
    plt.data_source.data['y'] = [i**power for i in x]
    push_notebook(handle=bokeh_handle)  


bokeh_handle = show(fig, notebook_handle=True)

##### new notebook cell #####

callback = CustomJS(code="""
if (IPython.notebook.kernel !== undefined) {
    var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
    cmd = "update_plot(" + cb_obj.value + ")";
    kernel.execute(cmd, {}, {});
}
""")

slider = Slider(start=0.1, 
                end=1,
                value=1,
                step=.05,
                title="power",
                callback=callback)
show(slider)
```

The idea is that the JS callback for the slider calls the python function `update_plot()`, which changes the data of the bokeh plot and then triggers a `push_notebook()`.

However, when I move the slider, the plot is not updated, but [some weird glyphs appear in the upper left corner (see red arrow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiZlm.png).

Executing `print(plt.data_source.data['y'])` showed me that the callback and `update_plot()` were actually called upon slider movement. Why is the plot not properly updated? Or am I missing something here?

(I know that I can do the same thing using `ipywidgets.interact`, but I want to stick to bokeh widgets.)

Comment: I can reproduce this, it seems like there might be a problem with update events (i.e. `push_notebook`) coming mid-flight during another ongoing event processing (the slider callback). The "weird glyph" is actually the entire plot shrunk down to the minimum canvas size (20x20px I think). I'd suggest filing an issue on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with this information.

Comment: Thx, the [issue is up](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5452)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the plot to update as expected by displaying the figure and the slider widget within a `bokeh.layouts.row` layout:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, push_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.layouts import row

output_notebook()

power = 0.5
x = [1,2,3]
y = [i**power for i in x]

fig = figure()
plt = fig.circle(x, y)

def update_plot(power):
    x = plt.data_source.data['x']
    plt.data_source.data['y'] = [i**power for i in x]
    push_notebook(handle=bokeh_handle)  


##### new notebook cell #####

callback = CustomJS(code="""
if (IPython.notebook.kernel !== undefined) {
    var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
    cmd = "update_plot(" + cb_obj.value + ")";
    kernel.execute(cmd, {}, {});
}
""")

slider = Slider(start=0.1, 
                end=1,
                value=1,
                step=.05,
                title="power",
                callback=callback)
bokeh_handle = show(row(fig, slider), notebook_handle=True)
```